# how to fix error "W: GPG error: on update BigBlueButton

Tags: apt, updates, update-manager, repository

```
root@webinar:~# sudo apt-get update
Get:1 http://ubuntu.bigbluebutton.org/xenial-200 bigbluebutton-xenial InRelease [2,510 B]
Ign:1 http://ubuntu.bigbluebutton.org/xenial-200 bigbluebutton-xenial InRelease
Hit:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Hit:3 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease
Hit:4 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease
Hit:5 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease
Fetched 2,510 B in 9s (255 B/s)
Reading package lists... Done
W: GPG error: http://ubuntu.bigbluebutton.org/xenial-200 bigbluebutton-xenial InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 37B5DD5EFAB46452
W: The repository 'http://ubuntu.bigbluebutton.org/xenial-200 bigbluebutton-xenial InRelease' is not signed.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Scenario:

BigBlueButton2 installed and run
File: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/bigbluebutton.list

Comment: how to fix error "W: GPG error: on update BigBlueButton for install BBB HTML5

Answer (score 2):

The message is telling you everything, you don't have the key for this repository on your system, the installation documentation is even telling this to use the following line to get the key in your keyring:

```
wget http://ubuntu.bigbluebutton.org/repo/bigbluebutton.asc -O- | sudo apt-key add -
```

This should solve it, if not they messed up their keys and you have to contact them.

Answer (score 0):

We're pretty sure the packages are properly signed.  Make sure you do all the steps in the docs, especially

http://docs.bigbluebutton.org/install/install.html#2-install-apt-get-key-for-bigbluebutton-repository

Regards,... Fred

BigBlueButton Developer